# Does Heston and SABR match market vol smile perfectly (arbitrage free)?

Tags: heston, sabr-model

What I saw in the references is

> Heston model can matches market option prices perfectly and SABR cannot.

Is it correct? But for my understanding, a model matches market option prices perfectly only when its equivalent local vol model should strictly follow Dupire equation (Dupire local vol model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mixes up various concepts:

- Exact fit of model to market prices. Neither Heston nor SABR can claim to fit exactly market prices. There are two reasons: both have a limited number of parameters (5 for Heston, 4 for SABR), and their corresponding models further restrict the shapes attainable with those parameters. Even for a small number (let's say 3) quotes at a given maturity, they are not guaranteed to match those exactly.
- Arbitrages in the parameterization: both stochastic volatility models do not allow arbitrage. But, for SABR, the practice is to use an approximation formula, which is not always arbitrage-free (it is only an approximation of the actual SABR stochastic volatility model).
- Dupire local vol: it is true that in presence of arbitrage the local vol is not defined (the local variance is negative). But by definition, the "equivalent local vol model" is the Dupire local vol model. There is no Dupire local vol model without a some continuous representation of the option prices, which may be realized via some specific interpolation, or via a stoch vol model. There is just one local vol model and it is arbitrage-free also by definition. There is also no need to go through Dupire to find out if the fit of a some model is perfect.

For a perfect fit, you typically need at least as many parameters as there are quotes (an approach sometimes called non-parametric). You could use a spline but this will not be arbitrage free in general. In terms of arbitrage-free methods, there is:

- [Andreasen Huge volatility interpolation](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1694972)
- [Le Floc'h arbitrage free interpolation of class C2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.08650)